# Why does TypeScript 3.7.5 throw an error when typing a function that receives an array?

Tags: typescript

I'm encountering an unexpected compiler error when typing a function that expects an array as its only argument.

Here's a minimum reproduction scenario: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgDEIIAFHMAZzgF44BvCnCFwIAOyYQAXHFEBXEACMkUANoBdHgD44ANwjAAJgBpBwsQCEUUaQEEoUFNQA8cxcu3dtewxQC+FCkxZUQxgMUZmAAowdg5pCTYITgBKfl8gA

```js
import React from 'react'

type FooProps = {
    onFoo: number[] => void,
    onBar: Array<number> => void
}

function Foo(props: FooProps) {}
```

Produces errors like "';' expected.ts(1005)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function type definitions have to include argument names (even though these are irrelevant) and be placed between parenthesis.

So your example should be altered like this (for example):

```js
type FooProps = {
    onFoo: (arg: number[]) => void;
    onBar: (arg: Array<number>) => void;
}
```

Note that I put semicolons after the function type definitions but these are not mandatory.

You can also define function types without the arrow syntax:

```js
type FooProps = {
    onFoo(arg: number[]): void;
    onBar(arg: Array<number>): void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type example:

```
type FooProps = {
    onFoo: (x: number[]) => void;
    onBar: (x: Array<number>) => void;
};
```

Interface example:

```
interface FooProps {
    onFoo: (x: number[]) => void;
    onBar: (x: Array<number>) => void;
}
```